# Given two Lists, the second being positive integers, repeat the first lists characters with the respective numbers in the second list

Tags: list, haskell

Trying to create a function which takes in two lists, the first being a list of characters, the second being positive integers. The function then repeats the characters in the first list the number of times the same position number in the second list is. Ex:

```
myCount ['a','b'] ['1','2'] => ['a','b','b']
```

What I have so far:

```
myCount :: [Char] -> [Int] -> [Char]       
myCount [] [] = []
myCount (x:xs) (y:ys) =  replicate y x && myCount xs ys
```

I am replicating the char from the first list (x) y times and then recursively doing this for the entire lists. 
Any help or pointers in the right direction would be great!

My Error is:

```
mess.hs:10:43: error:

* Couldn't match expected type `Bool' with actual type `[Char]'
* In the second argument of `(&&)', namely `myCount xs ys'
      In the expression: replicate y x && myCount xs ys
      In an equation for `myCount':
          myCount (x : xs) (y : ys) = replicate y x && myCount xs ys
```

Comment: How did you come up with the idea of using `&&` for this? That's a _logical and operator_.

Comment: @leftaroundabout was just trying to call the function until the list was empty, and I had used it before in another function I was making and it worked. It does seem to be my problem though.

Comment: In Haskell, it doesn't really make a lot of sense to “call functions until _X_”. You don't think about who calls whom, but how _the result should look_.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

How did you come up with the idea of using `&&` for this? That's a logical and operator, i.e. it combines two truth-values (`Bool`) to a value that's `True` only if both sides are true.

What you're dealing with are not boolean values but lists, though. You want to combine two *lists* to a list that starts with the first and continues with the other. IOW, you want a function with type `[Char] -> [Char] -> [Char]`. Actually it shouldn't matter that the list elements are `Char`s, this should work for lists containing *any* types: `[a] -> [a] -> [a]`.  Well, you can [hoogle that](https://www.haskell.org/hoogle/?hoogle=%5Ba%5D+-%3E+%5Ba%5D+-%3E+%5Ba%5D)! The [first result](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.9.0.0/docs/Prelude.html#v:-43--43-) is

```
(++) :: [a] -> [a] -> [a]                     infixr 5

     Append two lists, i.e.,

     [x1, ..., xm] ++ [y1, ..., yn] == [x1, ..., xm, y1, ..., yn]
     [x1, ..., xm] ++ [y1, ...] == [x1, ..., xm, y1, ...]

     If the first list is not finite, the result is the first list.
```

Sounds good, doesn't it? So, this is the function you're trying to write:

```
replicates :: [Int] -> [a] -> [a]
replicates (n:ns) (x:xs) =  replicate n x ++ replicates ns xs
replicates _ _ = []
```

Alternatively, you can define this as

```
replicates ns = concat . zipWith replicate ns
```

Comment: OK cool, I am new to Haskell and did not know there was this Hoogle site that explains this type of stuff. 
Is there a way to fix the issue I am having, in that the logical and operator is looking for true on both sides ?

Comment: Well yes, _don't use the logical operator_!

Comment: Ye I get what you mean now. Thanks for your help with this and that Hoogle site!